# How to show 1st column series behind 2nd series in Highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to combine the information "orders per weekday" and "orders per hour" in one column chart. The first series would show how many orders where placed on mondays, thuesdays, etc. and a second series would show the distribution between the different hours on each day. This would help to answers question "most orders are places on monday afternoons and sunday mornings..."

The result should look something like this:

[image]

The big columns represent the days and the red bars the hours (only four days and 5 hours per day in this example).

- How can I place the day-column behind the hour-column?
- How can I group the hour-column for each day with the corresponding day-column?

Comment: There are couple of options for defining columns positioning - grouping should be set to false, [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.pointRange) this should be set per series what is a valid range for a column - e.g. 24 hours or 1 hour. However, with columns it would be still tricky to achieve - I would use an area/arearange series with steps http://jsfiddle.net/8g6ddvv8/ or a polygon series http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.polygon